# Executing a Mysql query without selecting database in java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I want to execute a MySQL query without selecting a database in Java. I am able to do so directly in the MySQL console, like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  temptable
As(select REPLACE(a.keywordSupplied,"www.","") as keywordSupplied
from db1.table1 
;
```

I am able to execute the above query directly after logging into the MySQL console.I don't make use of the `use` statement here

```
use databasename;
```

I need to do this as I will be taking data from two different databases in a single query.
According to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm I gave DB URL as jdbc:mysql://localhost/

but it throws an `Exception`

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected.
```

Screenshot for the same in mysql console
[image]

Any solutions to make it work?

Comment: can you paste the url that you used?

Comment: @almasshaikh.
Here is the code snippet for connection
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", USER, PASS);

Comment: I believe the JDBC driver itself requires you to have selected a database (which in JDBC you should **not** do with `use database`, but with a call to `setCatalog` instead, or with explicitly specifying a database in the connection URL).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel."use databasename" is just to explain how it is done on mysql console. I am able to query without selecting any database(which is done using above quoted statement)  in case of myql console.
So i need to do the same using JAVA.

Comment: And I said that very likely it is not possible, because the driver itself requires a selected database.

Comment: *"I am able to [execute a query without selecting a database] directly in the MySQL console ..."* - I just tried that and it didn't work for me; I got "ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected". I suspect that when you connect via the console a database is being selected for you. Try this: Immediately after logging in to the MySQL console, run the command `SELECT DATABASE();`. If it returns something other than `NULL` then you actually do have a database selected.

Comment: @GordThompson.i have added the screenshot for mysql console

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", USER, PASS);
```

Use:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1", USER, PASS);//specify the db within URL itself.btw dont you have port in url?
```

Comment: Thats the main issue.I dont want to select any database as i will be getting data from two databses.So i need to do the whole task without selecting a database.And I am able to query without selecting a database in mysql console.I need to the same thing in JAVA.
And if I Try your solution than I am getting error "Unknown table temptable".

Comment: @almasshaikh If port is not specified in the URL, the default port will be used: 3306.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial you are following, they issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement. This statement is one of the very few statements that you can issue outside of the context of a database (the only other one I can think about is `CREATE USER`).

Even a `TEMPORARY` table must be attached to a database.

You *must* choose an arbitrary database for this operation. You probably do not care which one in particular (just make sure you have write permissions on the one you select :)

If you *really* do not want to provide a database at connection time, you can specify the target database in the SQL statement: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [database].temptable`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
System.out.println(conn);
conn.setCatalog("mysql");
PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  temptable (select test.a.id as id, students.a.id as sid from test.a join students.a on test.a.id = students.a.id)");
stmt1.execute();
stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from temptable");
ResultSet set1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
while(set1.next()){
    System.out.println(set1.getString(1));  
}
```

Now you have the connection with your database server execute your query. I hope your query will be execute without any problem.

Comment: i have done it already.When I try to execute any query It throws exception 
'java.sql.SQLException: No database selected'

Comment: actually problem is you are creating a table which always need a database . So don't create temp table or create and select temp database where your temp table will be created and then execute your query.

Comment: I have added more code and it is executing with any error. It is also displaying  data with select statement on temp table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you do "select * from test.demo;", it actually selects 'test' database and does the query in the 'demo' table.